# Изменение размера изображения пропорционально (изображение заданно матрицей NxM)

Tags: алгоритм

В двумерном массиве (матрице) задано изображение NxM, в каждом элементе матрицы хранится цвет соответствующего пикселя изображения.

Требуется уменьшить эту матрицу пропорционально (в K раз).

Например, уменьшить изображение в матрице в 3 раза, чтобы результат был примерно похож на тот, который мы бы получили при пропорциональном уменьшении размеров изображения в каком-нибудь графическом редакторе.

Какие есть алгоритмы для реализации подобной задачи?

Comment: http://eeweb.poly.edu/~yao/EL5123/lecture8_sampling.pdf

Comment: Так а графические редакторы по вашему как масштабируют?